# change Jquery loaded page URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code on my index.php page:

```
$('.EditCustomer').load("page1.php");

<select name="date" id="date" class="form-control">
...options here...
</select>
```

i then have this on `page1.php` which should change `page1.php` to be `page1.php?date=1234`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#date').on('change', function() {
            $('.EditCustomer').load("page1.php?date=" + $(this).val());
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

but its not doing it because it cannot find the `.EditCustomer` div

how can i make it change the page1.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL using the history object:

[Manipulating the history/url of page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method)

```
history.replaceState(null, null, "page1.php?date=" + $(this).val());
```

Though i'm not sure this is what you are looking for.